# Check for dpkg frontend lock using python

Tags: python, automation

I'm writing a pthon script to install several setups and configs. but before installing that i want to check if the dpkg frontend is locked or not.

sample

```
if(checkfordpkg() == true):
 print("dpkg frontend is locked")
else:
 installconfigs()
```

can someone help me out with this part. I cannot think of a way to check the dpkg frontend lock using python.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect whether `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` exists on a Debian-based system?

Comment: `pathlib.Path("/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend").exists()`